# Discrete mathematics: chances of getting specific card on card-game

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, card-games

The game is played with a deck of $40$ cards. Three of them are dealt to each of two players, so **my hand**, the cards that were given to me, is formed by three cards of the deck.

At the same time, four type of cards exist: *gold, swords, chalice, lumber*. The deck of $40$ cards is formed by ten of each of these types.

I was requested to answer what is more likely: to be dealt a hand that contains the *1 of swords* (the strongest card), or a hand that contains a $6$ and a $7$ of the same type, whatever that type is.

I have advanced this further, but I'm not really sure if my reasoning is okay.

Let $A = \{1, 2, 3, ..., 40\}$ all the cards.

Let $S = \{1, 2, 3, ...,10\}$, $G = \{11, 12, 13, ..., 20\}$, $C = \{21, 22, 23, ..., 30\}$, $L = \{31, 32, 33, ..., 40\}$ be the subsets of $A$ formed by cards of type swords, gold, chalice and lumber, respectively.

I know there are $\binom{40}{3} = 9880$ subsets of three elements of $A$, *i.e* $9880$ possible hands. Of those subsets, which of them contains the element $1$? In other words, which of those hands contains the 1 of swords?

Well, those that *do not* contain $1$ are subsets of $A'=A-\{1\}$, and there are $\binom{39}{3}=9139$ subsets of $A'$. All subset of $A'$ is also a subset of $A$, therefore there are $9139$ subsets of $A$ that *do not* contain the element $1$. From this it follows that there are $9880-9139=741$ subsets of $A$ that do contain $1$, or rather $741$ possible hands with the 1 of swords. From all the hands, this $741$ are just $\frac{741}{9880}*100=7.5$ percent. So there's a $7.5\%$ chances of getting a hand with the 1 of swords.

I have to main problems:

a) I'm not sure my reasoning is completely right about the chances of getting a hand with the one of swords.

b) How do I find the chances of getting a hand with a $6$ and a $7$ of the same type, whatever that type is? This is the same as asking for the chances of getting a subset of $A$ with $6, 7$ or $16, 17$ or $26, 27$ or $36, 37$ in it.

EDIT: Please note that, in the answer of how many hands would contain $1$, hands that include $1$ and pair of values $6, 7$, $16, 17$, etc., are included. In the answer of how many hands contain the pairs $6, 7$ or $16, 17$, etc., can and should contain those that also contain $1$.

I'm very sorry for the long post, it was either this or not showing what I've tried already. Thank you!

Comment: Note that the $741$ is correct if you consider the four hands $\{1, 6, 7\}$, $\{1, 16, 17\}$, $\{1, 26, 27\}$, and $\{1, 36, 37\}$ to be included in the same group. Is that what you want? Similarly, you need to clarify if the "hand with $6$ and $7$ of same type" should exclude these.

Comment: You're right, I should. I will edit this. And yes, the hands that contain the $1$ and the desired pair of numbers do not exclude each other, and should be contained in both answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hand that contains the 1 of swords must contain $2$ of the remaining $39$ cards.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{1}{1}\binom{39}{2} = 741$$
such hands as you found.  The probability of obtaining a hand containing a 1 of swords is
$$\frac{\dbinom{1}{1}\dbinom{39}{2}}{\dbinom{40}{3}}$$

A hand that contains both a 6 and 7 of the same type must contain one of the remaining $38$ cards in the deck.  There are four ways to choose the suit and $38$ ways to choose the remaining card, so there are
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{2}{2}\binom{38}{1} = 152$$
such hands.  The probability of obtaining a hand that contain both a 6 and 7 of the same suit is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{4}{1}\dbinom{2}{2}\dbinom{38}{1}}{\dbinom{40}{3}}$$

Hence, it is more likely that a hand contains a 1 of swords than a 6 and 7 of the same suit.

Comment: This is actually true. As always one feels a bit silly when one's question is asked so flawlesly and simply, haha! Thanks!